# PHP SwiftMailer Telus email connection error

Tags: php, swiftmailer, webmail

With Swift mailer i have tried with gmail, it works fine.
But not working with telus.

My information is below.

```
SMTP
Server: webmail.washtech.ca
Port:   25
SSL:    No
```

I have writen the connection line as below.

```
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('webmail.washtech.ca', 25)
```

I am getting the following error on page.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Connection could not be established with host
>   webmail.washtech.ca [Connection refused #111]' in
>   swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(62):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1
>   swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(113):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2
>   swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 phpmailer.php(40):
>   Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 home.php(16):
>   send_email('', '$email_address', '', '', 'Heading', 'Test. in
>   swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line
>   269

Can you please tell me what i can change in code?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to connect with smtp to a webmail client - this cannot work.

ask the administrator of washtech.ca if they provide smtp, you can try mail.washtech.ca.

Comment: I have smtp for that. Its also not working.

smtp.telus.net

Comment: can you connect with a regular mail client and send messages? (i.e. thunderbird or outlook)